# Image upload gems that don't require RMagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image

I was wondering if anyone knew if there were any good image upload gems for Ruby on Rails 3 that don't require RMagick?

Answer (score 0):

image_science is a great alternative to RMagick, though it has nothing to do with upload, just image processing / image manipulation.

http://seattlerb.rubyforge.org/ImageScience.html

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding you need RMagick only if you need to process (for example resize) the images. For just uploading RMagick is not necessary.

Comment: but to use gems like Paperclip its needed. I would like to just have avatars